# VS Community 2019 error while installing Analysis Service and Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add in the extensions to Visual Studio Community 2019 the Analysis Services and the Reporting Services and every time I get the error below.  I have tried to clean the Temp file and then repair the community version but I am still getting this error and I can't use .BIM Model in my project until I get these working.

What do I need to do to get this working?
Thank you!
JB

*

> 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM -
> ------------------------------------------- 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version: 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM - 16.9.1050 3/11/2021
> 3:41:06 PM - ------------------------------------------- 3/11/2021
> 3:41:06 PM - Command line parameters: 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM -
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\berglunj\Downloads\Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix,/callingprocessid:18488,/installas:3232
> 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM - -------------------------------------------
> 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM -
> ------------------------------------------- 3/11/2021 3:41:06 PM - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not all privileges
> or groups referenced are assigned to the caller    at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.SetPrivilege(String privilegeName, Int32
> attrib)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnterDebugMode()    at
> VSIXInstaller.UserImpersonationHelper.DuplicateSuppliedToken(IntPtr
> token, UInt32 callingProcessId)    at
> VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
> VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
> exceptionObject)

- 

Answer (score 7):

Run Powershell as Administrator and go to file

Example (if file save on Desktop):

```
cd ~\Desktop\

.\file.vsix
```

Comment: This solved it! The issue was that the permissions were missing to install the extension

Comment: This worked for me with the default Windows 7 command line, when run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like missing permissions

> (0x80004005): Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller at System.Diagnostics.Process.SetPrivilege(String privilegeName, Int32 attrib) at  System.Diagnostics.Process.EnterDebugMode() at

assuming you ran this as admin, it could be missing debug privileges. in our infrastructure for example, we have removed debug privileges for admins.

this can be found in secpol.msc (or GPO editor) in path
Computer Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies/User Rights Assignment / Debug Programs

i currently have no explanation why some vsix packages need this privilege, because not all do (and requiring debug privs for package installations makes not a lot of sense IMHO)

Comment: Thank you.  It did work when I ran the Visual Studio program as admin and it let the update complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need admin privilage to run the VSIX setup.

1. Run Visual Studio with Administrator privilege by

   > right click the VS icon -> Run as asministrator
2. Install the VSIX via the Extension
3. VSIX should be installed and solve the problem.