# Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to install **Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project** in my **Visual Studio Enterprise 2022**, using **Manage Extension**. I'm getting this below error.

```
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - 17.4.2119
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - Command line parameters:
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:17.4.33122.133,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\kkabh\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXzfphzvnr.vsix,/callingprocessid:19328,/installas:2568
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:56:44 - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.SetPrivilege(String privilegeName, Int32 attrib)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnterDebugMode()
   at VSIXInstaller.UserImpersonationHelper.DuplicateSuppliedToken(IntPtr token, UInt32 callingProcessId)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I tried downloading the extension from Marketplace and now getting a different error, as below.

```
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - 17.4.2119
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - Command line parameters:
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\kkabh\Downloads\InstallerProjects.vsix
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - -------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:47 - Initializing Install...
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - Extension Details...
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Identifier         : VSInstallerProjects
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Name               : Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Author             : Microsoft
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Version            : 1.0.2
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Description        : This official Microsoft extension provides support for Visual Studio Installer Projects in Visual Studio.
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Locale             : en-US
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6.1,)
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   SignatureState     : ValidSignature
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Certificate Info   : 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       -------------------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       [Serial Number] : 3300000463CA7009C09247FA42000000000463
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       [Not Before]    : 02-09-2021 23:56:31
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       [Not After]     : 01-09-2022 23:56:31
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       [Thumbprint]    : 909438EC2298CCB370EEAF0453E440A8DCBBC166
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Supported Products : 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -           Version : [15.0,17.0)
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -           ProductArchitecture : x86
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   References         : 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Prerequisites      : 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       -------------------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Name         : Visual Studio Min Shell
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Version      : [15.0.26205,17.0)
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       -------------------------------------------------------
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Name         : ClickOnce Publishing
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -       Version      : [15.0,17.0)
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - Signature Details...
22-12-2022 19:48:48 -   Extension is signed with a valid signature.
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - 
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - Searching for applicable products...
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - Found installed product - Global Location
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
22-12-2022 19:48:48 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I actually need to generate an installation package. For that I tried this. If there are any option for generating the installation package, please let me know.

But still, it may be needed to download some other extension seems.
I actually tried some other extension, downloaded using **Manage Extension**, but result was negative.
Please help me out of this!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue you report, but this different issue has the same solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72980594/241161

Instead of elevating after running, the suggestion was to start an elevated session in Powershell, and start the run from an elevated (Administrator) user. That did the trick.